# Spring mvc - get data from other server, what object to use and how to reuse it?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have some url that I need to read data from there and use it in my controller.
Usually in java application I use http client, to get data from some url.
My questions are:
 What object to use in spring mvc to get data from some url (like http client) ?
 How to reuse this objects, so every time not to create it ?

Thank you!

Comment: Just because you're using Spring doesn't mean you can't continue to use HttpClient or whatever method you previously use to fetch remote data...

Comment: How to reuse the httpclient ?

Comment: http://spring.io/blog/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In agreement with the comment by @Evgeny and @Beau above, you can use any client library you like.  HttpClient is VERY bean friendly and, for cases where it might be difficult to construct the configuration, you can always provide a Spring factory bean to construct the object.

If you are looking to abstract away the plumbing of the HttpClient API usage, utilize the RestTemplate suggested by @Evgeny (I believe that it is also his brainchild) It is a VERY rich and simple API to leverage.